# WCF AddServiceEndpoint cannot find ServiceContract Attribute

Tags: wcf

I have server code that has been shelved for awhile and I went back to test it.

We create a `ServiceHost` in a class and we add endpoints to the `ServiceHost`. When we add an endpoint we are getting an exception saying:

> [the ServiceContract attribute cannot be found.]

But the attribute is there and I have added code to get the attributes and verify it is there.

```
 public static void AddEndPoint ( ServiceHost host, string url, Type implementsType )
 {
    var binding = CreateBinding( url );



    var attrs = implementsType.GetCustomAttributes ( false );

    host.AddServiceEndpoint ( implementsType, binding, url );
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello ( string name );
}
```

I have created an example **sln** that works fine where all libraries are .net framework libraries.

In regular **sln** our service interfaces are in a **.net standard 2.0 library**, our services are in a **.net framework library** and the project that creates the service host is a **.net framework library**. I cannot figure out why if the attribute is there when viewed in the attrs array and yet AddServiceEndPoint does not find it.

Comment: Make sure your regular .NET framework projects are 4.6.1

Comment: We are using 4.7.2 why would 4.6.1 help?

Comment: Well you say the contracts/interfaces are .NET Standard 2.0.  That implies **4.6.1**.    So if your service implementation project or any other dependent project was `earlier than that` you would have problems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: I see. No all .net framework projects uses 4.7.2 and .net standard library uses .net core 2.

Comment: Goodo. FYI -  .NET Core 2 is part of .NET Standard 2.